# Can SSR outputs be considered dry contacts?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

To save board space I want to replace relays with SSRs where possible. Most of the relays I use don't need to carry a lot of current and don't to switch high voltages. Mostly slow 24V digital signals to connect to other devices working at other potentials.

Classically relays are use for this, but SSRs would be a lot more convenient.

The question is: Can SSRs designed for DC voltages switch currents at arbitrary potentials (obviously < isolation voltage). There is really not much information about this.

Comment: A SSR will have specifications for minimum and maximum switching voltage and current, so it will work within those limits. I'm not sure what else you're asking.

Comment: The voltage between the output terminals will be small. I am not worried about that. What I was worried about is the voltage difference between my device and the external device connected to the output. Since they are sourced from different supplies and galvanically isolated they can have an arbitrary voltage difference. My question is, if this makes a difference or if it is irrelevant as long as it's less than the isolation voltage.

Comment: Yes, most DC compatible SSR's are fundamentally ok for 24V plc logic (worst case is type 2 input, max 30V 30mA; most systems now type1/type3 which is 15mA max I believe). For switching non-logic loads etc, check the specs.

Comment: @PeteW What do you mean by "type 1/2/3"?

Comment: @Karsten -- there is an IEC 61131 standard for 24V PLC logic signals, and it defines 3 "types", meaning the min/max voltages and currents for the on and off states. [see here, pages 4-5](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=70620). It dates back to when typical circuitry was very power-hungry by modern standards, so now types 1 and 3 are most commonly supported, in light of balancing power dissipation vs reasonable device size.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> The voltage between the output terminals will be small. I am not worried about that.

You need to be concerned with that. There will be a minimum switching voltage and the SSR will have to be chosen for DC or AC load switching.

> What I was worried about is the voltage difference between my device and the external device connected to the output. Since they are sourced from different supplies and galvanically isolated they can have an arbitrary voltage difference. My question is, if this makes a difference or if it is irrelevant as long as it's less than the isolation voltage.

One of the main features of SSRs is the electrical isolation. Typical isolation voltages will be four to ten times the working voltage to protect against lighting or other spikes in voltage. So if you're switching 230 - 240 V mains voltage you should be looking for an isolation rating of 1 kV to 4 kV or greater.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a dangerous assumption. The phrase "dry contact" has historically referred to a traditional switch or relay contact, which has an impedance of an air gap when in the open condition (infinite for practical purposes, at least when arcing does not occur).

An SSR uses a semiconductor switch, as well as an internal snubber network, which therefore has some leakage current in the open state (in other words the open circuit resistance can be very high but finite).

You would need to take this into account for your application - and also check whether older equipment might be connected which might have been designed before SSR's were in common use.

Another factor is that dry contacts have traditionally been provide logic signalling between systems which must remain electrically isolated. You would need to consider whether the requirements for isolation are being met by the SSR under all circumstances.

[This FAQ from Omron](https://www.ia.omron.com/support/faq/answer/18/faq02155/) discusses certain possible "gotchas" for SSR's which would not generally be encountered with a conventional relay.

Answer (score 0):

The SSR could replace in some cases mechanical relays.You should check compatibility. Commutating voltage, load current, contact resistance.
Take as an example lh15801 from Vishay. Another manufacturers have same devices. Like Toshiba tlp748j. If  resistance not critical, commutating small currents, replacing should not be a problem.